# Error when installing tensorflow on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, installation, pip

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B with Ubuntu Server 20.04 and I'm getting an error when trying to install tensorflow.

```
ubuntu@pi1:~$ pip3 install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

ubuntu@pi1:~$ pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I have Python 3.8.5 64-bit installed

```
ubuntu@pi1:~$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'ELF')
>>>
```

My pip is also >19.0

```
ubuntu@pi1:~$ pip3 -V
pip 20.3.3 from /home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Comment: rpi is 64bit ARM, not the same as x86_64 (amd64).

Comment: @jordanm I've also tried the link https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/raspberrypi/tensorflow-2.3.0rc2-cp35-none-linux_armv6l.whl which is for rpi but I get the same error, says it's not a supported wheel

Comment: Yes but that package is for arm6vl, which is not 64-bit, you need a aarch64/arm64 package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment section for the benefit of the community.

You need to look for `aarch64/arm64` package in order to install `Tensorflow` on `Ubuntu 20.4`.